# How to make an HTML class property conditional based on a value in the model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

For the code snippet below how can I make the "collapse" attribute conditional based on a property in my model

```
<div id="AlertError" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible collapse" role="alert">
    <div id="AlertMsg">@Model.SvrErrorMsg</div>
    <button type="button" class="close" id="linkclose" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Would the following idea below work?

```
<div id="AlertError" class="@(model.ShowError == "true" ? "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" : "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible collapse")" role="alert">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a common way, and it works fine ( in my code is `Model` instead of `model` ). You can see the details of the page in the developer tools.

[image]

You can also use JavaScipt to judge:

```
<div id="AlertError" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert" value="@Model.ShowError" ></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var value = $("#AlertError").attr("value");
        if(value != "true")
        {
            $("#AlertError").addClass("collapse");
        }

    });
</script>
```

Also, just a suggestion, if your `ShowError` property only has two values, true and false, you can use boolean type instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

No need to repeat all classes. You can do it like this:

```
<div id="AlertError" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible @(Model.ShowError ? null : "collapse")" role="alert"></div>
```